# I want to push the data to html web page from my java program

Tags: java, html, ajax

I want to push the data to html web page from my java program without any request..both are different remote machine.. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Have you tried using commons http client to make an http request? Check http://hc.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet and from service method you can write your response.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I got the data throug a webservice.and i want to push the data to one of my remote machines.

Comment: please explain your requirement first. Are you using any server?

Comment: ok..Thank you for the reponse.I have a server.I am creating some webservice to recieve and sent data to an application.That application is in a remote location.If a have the data then how can i push the data to the html page,

Comment: I am using java   ,   html   ,javascript  ,Ajax

Comment: So you want to push from a web server to client  without any request??

Comment: Yes it is possible with long polling,websockets etc.